# Qt Drop event not firing

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

Drop event will not happen, although `setAcceptDrops' has been called. The following code is based on a widget project created with Qt 5.12.0. After adding in dropEvent() function the cpp file becomes

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug> // added

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true); // added
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

// added; in .h it is in `protected:' section
void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dropEvent";
}
```

What am I missing? I have been struggling for a few days... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your widget have child widgets?

Comment: No child widgets at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to overwrite the dragEnterEvent method that allow you to filter by the data type, by the source, by the type of action. In the following example, everything is accepted:

***.h**

```
// ...
protected:
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) override;
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override;
// ...
```

***.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true); // added
}

// ...
void MainWindow::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dropEvent" << event;
}
void MainWindow::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

For more detail I recommend you read [`Drag and Drop`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html).

Comment: It worked in this. In my real project I had a QListWidget-derived widget on the main window, adding dragEnterEvent and dropEvent the same as your solution. The drop event won't happen. Weird...

Comment: @jianz Have you implemented those methods inside the class of the custom QListWidget?

Comment: Yes. Those methods are inside the .h file of the custom widget - if that's what you meant.

Comment: @jianz maybe you have implemented it incorrectly, you can upload your project to github to be able to review it easily

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found out what was causing it. In my case, it was because I was trying to drag and drop a file onto a QTextEdit widget instead of the MainWindow. As it turns out, nothing happens because the dragEnterEvent and dropEvent functions are defined for MainWindow and not for QTextEdit.

Comment: OP said that their widget has no child widgets, and that their `dragEnterEvent` and `dropEvent` are defined for their widget, how is your answer related to their question?

Comment: @Mihoub Abderrahmene Rayene I was new to Qt and encountered the 'drop event not firing' issue. At the time, I realized that the cause of the problem might be different for others who were asking the same question, so I explained what caused the issue in my particular case. My response was mostly to share my incorrect experience and may not provide a direct answer to the question.