# QListWidget-derived: drop event not firing

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

A widget derived from QListWidget is the only widget on a window. Function "setAcceptDrops(true);" is used in its constructor, and "event->accept();" is called in its "dragEnterEvent". However, its "dropEvent" could not be triggered. Please check the whole source code (created using Qt 5.12.0) at
github.com/jianz-github/dropevent.

I have asked a question at [Qt Drop event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870847/qt-drop-event-not-firing). This situation is supposed to be the same, but it is not.  Weird.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the solution is to overwrite the `dragMoveEvent()` method as well.

**listbox.h**

```
#ifndef LISTBOX_H
#define LISTBOX_H

#include <QListWidget>
#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>

class ListBox : public QListWidget
{
public:
    ListBox(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) override;
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override;
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event) override;
};

#endif // LISTBOX_H
```

**listbox.cpp**

```
#include "listbox.h"
#include <QDebug>

ListBox::ListBox(QWidget *parent) : QListWidget (parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}
void ListBox::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "dropEvent"<<event;
}
void ListBox::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
void ListBox::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    event->acceptProposedAction();
}
```

Comment: I accepted your answer - it works. However, why in this case dragMoveEvent() is necessary but the mainWindow only case drageMoveEvent() is not necessary?